# Windows 10 File Explorer crashes when I want to open the Control Panel

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, crash

I am having problems trying to copy and paste files in Windows 10 and I can't open the control panel. I am getting the following error message:

> Windows Explorer has stopped working 
>   Windows is checking for a solution for the problem

And a few moments later..

> Windows Explore is restarting

But after that the error is not resolved.

Here is the error log message from the Event Viewer:

> Faulting application name: explorer.exe, version: 6.2.10586.589, time 
>   stamp: 0x57cf9743 
>   Faulting module name: shellex.dll, version:
>   16.0.0.694, time stamp: 0x56cc98f5 
>   
> Exception code: 0xc0000005 
>   
> Fault offset: 0x0000000000007f3b 
>   
> Faulting process ID: 0x%9 
>   
> Faulting application start time: 0x%10 
>   
> Faulting application path: %11
>   
> Faulting module path: %12 
>   
> Report ID: %13 
>   
> Faulting package full name: %14
>   Faulting package-relative application ID: %15

I think this problem began when I upgraded Kaspersky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file shellex.dll crashes your explorer:

```
Faulting module name: shellex.dll, version: 16.0.0.694, time stamp: 0x56cc98f5
```

Doing a [google search shows](http://fxexe.com/file/shellex.dll/128551) that the file is indeed part of Kaspersky. Look again for a new update.